# azure VM extension Powershell Custom script

Tags: terraform

I want to pass the variables inside my terraform script when I call the PowerShell script inside "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension". i don't know how to pass arguments to my powershell script. I have used the following code.

"commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file ${var.main_hybridscriptname} -AAResourceGroupName ${var.aobclResourceGroup} -OMSResourceGroupName ${var.aobclResourceGroup} -SubscriptionID ${var.azure_subscription_id} -AutomationAccountName ${module.automationAccount.AutomationName} -HybridGroupName ${var.hybridgroupname} -WorkspaceName ${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.aobclloganalyticsworkspace.name} -appidSPN ${var.SPN_APP_ID} -SPNpswd ${var.SPN_PSWD} -tenantID ${var.azure_tenant_id}"

error in script execution when i use a script of test without argument, it works**strong text**

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] please? It would also help if you also included the full error output too.

Comment: Just I am bloqued in the command to execute because I don't know how to pass parameters to my powershell script

Comment: But can you edit your question to include a workable example that people can run? And also show the error. From a glance it looks like you are already doing the right thing but it's hard to tell without seeing a full, workable example and, more importantly, the error you get.